# How to pass a directory path to os.execvp

Tags: python, exec, system-calls, rethinkdb, execvp

I'm trying to [change directory path of RethinkDB](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/cli-options/) while executing from Python.

This Bash command is working:

```
rethinkdb --directory ~/ComeOnRethink
```

But this system call is not working:

```
args = ("--directory ~/ComeOnRethink",) # RethinkDB directory to store data and metadata
os.execvp("rethinkdb", args)
```

It's ignoring the argument and executing RethinkDB with default path. How can I fix this problem?

*This is working:

```
subprocess.Popen(['rethinkdb', '--directory', './ComeOnRethink'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os.path
args = ["rethinkdb", "--directory", os.path.expanduser("~/ComeOnRethink")]
os.execvp("rethinkdb", args) # assumes 'rethinkdb' can be found in a directory listed in the PATH environment variable
```

`args` should be an iterable of command line words (as parsed by the shell, including the command name).

`os.path.expanduser` will replace the `~` in the path argument to the user's home directory (which is something `bash` does for you).

Comment: It says `ERROR: Unrecognized subcommand '~/ComeOnRethink'. Try 'rethinkdb help'.`

Comment: right... I focused on the syntax of `os.execvp`. The other problem you have is that the shell expands `~` to the current user's home directory; that is something that `os.execvp` won't do for you.

Comment: It says `ERROR: Unrecognized subcommand './ComeOnRethink'. Try 'rethinkdb help'.` Did you really try?

Comment: My problem is `COMMAND ARGUMENT` is working but `COMMAND ARGUMENT VALUE` is not working.

Comment: out of practice... the first argument (in `args`) should be the actual command name. Corrected.

Comment: Why in the world do you need to repeat the command name in args!? Pretty confusing....any explanations?

Comment: @BluePython The first argument is the path to the executable itself (which must be a valid path), the second argument is the first argument in the executed process `argv` array (i.e. `sys.argv[0]` in Python). They are not strictly required to be the same but in practice they are the same more often than not.